# compare two array value and get the same value indexOf in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to compare two array value and the get index, for example,

```
var X = ['10.3', '1.2', '5','10', '1', '15','1.33'];
var Y = ['1.68','0.65', '1', '9', '5', '31.3'];
```

i need to compare this `X` and `Y` array, if `X` and `Y` values are equal in which index the both values are equal, that time i need the `X` `indexOf` value only i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and check if the value exists. If so take an object with index and value for the result set.

```js
var x = ['10.3', '1.2', '5', '10', '1', '15', '1.33'],
    y = ['1.68', '0.65', '1', '9', '5', '31.3'],
    ySet = new Set(y),
    result = x.reduce((r, value, index) => (ySet.has(value) && r.push({ value, index }), r), []);
    
console.log(result);
```